# Vertical Separator Primefaces 5.0

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi I need to use a vertical separator on a jsf form using primefaces 5.0, does anyone have any idea how can I do it?? I've already tried :

and modifying mi .css but neither of them worked out...

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.vSeparator {
    border-left: 1px dotted #000000;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="vSeparator"></span>
```